# Regex find and replace inbetween Latex enviroment

Tags: regex, perl, latex

I'm trying to come up with a regex to use in find and replace so I can find all '(' characters used inside of the align environment.
Example text:

```
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum 
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum (Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum )
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum 
\begin{align}
\frac{d_l}{2}< |\epsilon_H(g(m))| <\frac{d_r}{2} 
\frac{d_l}{2}< |\epsilon_H(g(m))| <\frac{d_r}{2} 
\end{align}
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum 
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
```

I then want to find all the '(' inside of `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}`and NOT inside the main body of text. I so far have the regex:

```
(?<=\{align\})\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(?=\\end\{align\})
```

but this only finds ALL the text inside the environment and not the individual instances of '('.

(The reason behind this is because I need to go through my whole document and change all the '(' inside the equations to '`\left(`' and I don't want to change any parentheses occurring in the text that may be used.)

Comment: With Perl you can try this `(?:\\begin{align}|\G(?!\A))(?:(?!\\end{align})[^(])*\K\(` . See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/sfFyVu/1

Comment: If the opening parenthesis should be between \begin{align} and \end{align} you could use a positive lookahead `(?s)(?:\G(?!^)|\\begin{align})[^(]+\K\((?=.*\\end{align})` and make the dot match a newline https://regex101.com/r/z4UVpi/1

Comment: or use range operator in scalar context (flip-flop) i.e. `if (/^\\begin\{align\}/../^\\end\{align\}) { ... processing that should happen only inside the align block goes here... }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the range operator (`..`) in scalar context, i.e. as flip-flop, to isolate the blocks you want to work on.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<STDIN>) {
    if (/^\\begin\{align\}/../^\\end\{align\}/) {
        # replace all occurences of "(" with "\left("
        s/\(/\\left(/g;
    }
    print;
}

exit 0;
```

Test run with your given text:

```
$ perl dummy.pl <dummy.txt
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum (Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum )
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
\begin{align}
\frac{d_l}{2}< |\epsilon_H\left(g\left(m))| <\frac{d_r}{2}
\frac{d_l}{2}< |\epsilon_H\left(g\left(m))| <\frac{d_r}{2}
\end{align}
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
```

Or as one-liner:

```
$ perl <dummy.txt -pe 's/\(/\\left(/g if (/^\\begin\{align\}/../^\\end\{align\}/)'
...
\frac{d_l}{2}< |\epsilon_H\left(g\left(m))| <\frac{d_r}{2}
\frac{d_l}{2}< |\epsilon_H\left(g\left(m))| <\frac{d_r}{2}
...
```

If the block detection is too strict, i.e. in your real document the `\begin` and `\end` are not at the beginning of the line, then try the following without the `^` (caret):

```perl
 if (/\\begin\{align\}/../\\end\{align\}/) {
```

Comment: thanks, I ran this on my text however I didn't get any output of the replacements

Comment: Maybe you need to make the begin/end regex a little less strict. They currently *only* match if the begin/end are at the beginning of the line. That works for the example you provided.

Comment: I've added a less tight begin/end detection regex to my answer.

Comment: thanks worked beautifully! the more flexible block detection worked

Answer (score 5):

There are two techniques for accomplishing the given task. One is starting match from `\\begin{align}` and two is signaling engine to stop matching `(` right after facing with `\\end{align}`.

The first step could be taken using `\G` token and the second is a job for a restrictive match or tempered-`[^(]`.

```
(?:\\begin{align}|\G(?!\A))(?:(?!\\end{align})[^(])*\K\(
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/sfFyVu/2)

Perl code:

```
my $regex = qr/(?:\\begin{align}|\G(?!\A))(?:(?!\\end{align})[^(])*\K\(/p;
my $subst = '\\\\left(';
my $result = $str =~ s/$regex/$subst/rg;
```

See [live demo here](https://ideone.com/RDjIV3)

Regex breakdown:

- `(?:` Start of non-capturing group

  - `\\begin{align}` Match `\begin{align}` literally
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!\A)` Start match from where previous match ends
- `)` End of non-capturing group
- `(?:` Start of NCG

  - `(?!\\end{align})` Until we reach `\end{align}`
  - `[^(]` Try to match a non-`(` character
- `)*` End of NCG, repeat as much as possible
- `\K\(` Reset matched portion and try to match `(`

One-liner:

```
perl -0777 -i.bak -pe 's~(?:\\begin\{align}|\G(?!\A))(?:(?!\\end\{align})[^(])*\K\(~\\left(~g;' file
```

Comment: You can run it against the whole file content. What's the problem?

Comment: i'm running perl -plwe 's/(?s)(?:\G(?!^)|\\begin{align})[^(]+\K\((?=.*\\end{align})/\\left\\(/;' LHSOptions-rewrite-2-5-2_copy.tex > testout.tex and the matches are still not being replaced